# continuous map from indiscrete space

Tags: general-topology

Show that a continuous map from indiscrete space X to a $T_0$  space must be constant function. I was trying to prove it by contradiction. If the map f is not constant then there is two points x, y s.t. f(x) not equals f(y), then used $T_0$ property.Then what to do so that we arrive a contradiction. Is the method is going to be fruitful?

Comment: You are on the right track. At least one of the points, let's say $f(x)$ is contained in an open set $U$ that does not contain $f(y)$. The preimage of this set must be open (since $f$ is continuous). That means that it must equalize the empty set or $X$. Can you think further from here?

Comment: I think it will make the indiscrete space X $T_0$.... (?), can not write it properly.

Comment: By "equalize the empty set or $X$", drhab meant it's not empty nor is it the whole space. So, $f^{-1}(U)$ is a non-empty open set that's not all of $X$. So ...

Comment: not getting..... please explain

Comment: Well..  if $X$ has the indiscrete topology, what are the only open sets?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**:

If in your context $f(x)\neq f(y)$ then  $f\left(x\right)\in U$ and $f\left(y\right)\notin U$ (or $f\left(y\right)\in U$ and $f\left(x\right)\notin U$) for an open set $U$. Since $f$ is continuous, set $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$
is open in indiscrete space $X$. So $f^{-1}\left(U\right)\in\left\{ \emptyset,X\right\} $.
Both 'possibilities' lead to a contradiction. You could also say that there are no possibilities, so the assumption $f(x)\neq f(y)$ cannot be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for your remark. :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose there is a non-constant continuous map and consider the preimage of certain open sets in the $T_0$ space which are guaranteed to exist by the fact that it is $T_0$ (note that the space has to have more than $1$ element because otherwise the function would be constant).